# Join two table and show different column on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have this table

table "assign" --> npwp,kpp,cab,nip_ar,klu --> has 31.023 data

and

table "masterfile" --> npwp,kpp,cab,jenis,nama,kota --> has 33.631 data

i want to join those two table so I can get, npwp,kpp,cab,jenis,nama,kota,nip_ar,klu

When I use LEFT JOIN, it processed so long time. But when i use UNION ALL, it doesn't work as what i want.

these my UNION ALL query :

> SELECT npwp,kpp,NULL as author,cab,nip_ar,klu FROM assign GROUP BY npwp,kpp,cab UNION ALL SELECT npwp,kpp,cab,jenis,nama,kota FROM masterfile GROUP BY npwp,kpp,cab;

I just get column npwp,kpp,author,cab,nip_ar,klu. but column jenis,nama,kota not shown.

and these my LEFT JOIN query :

> SELECT masterfile.npwp,masterfile.kpp,masterfile.cab,masterfile.name,masterfile.address,assign.nip_ar,assign.klu FROM masterfile LEFT JOIN assign ON assign.npwp=masterfile.npwp AND assign.kpp=masterfile.kpp AND assign.cab=masterfile.cab;

Im newbie on query, please help me to fix this problem.
thank you so much.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with your `OUTER JOIN` -- do you have indices on joined columns?  Using `UNION` is completely different from using `JOINs`, depends on your desired results.

Comment: yes you right sgeddes, just must add index on it, thank you so much for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I get the answer from my friend on party chat,

that my join query is good, just must be add INDEX in column NPWP,KPP,CAB on both table masterfile and assign so the query can processed faster.

> SELECT masterfile.npwp,masterfile.kpp,masterfile.cab,masterfile.name,masterfile.address,assign.nip_ar,assign.klu FROM masterfile LEFT JOIN assign ON assign.npwp=masterfile.npwp AND assign.kpp=masterfile.kpp AND assign.cab=masterfile.cab;